# Troubleshooting strange recurring McAfee console messages (OS X)

Tags: macos, crash, process

I uninstalled McAfee anti-virus long ago. I tried to completely scrub it from the system but apparently some vestige remains.

I get spurts of Console messages like these every few seconds:

> 6/21/16 10:28:01.522 AM ReportCrash[19417]: Attempt to read info_array
>   in pid 19425 failed, address was 8fe53ef0 6/21/16 10:28:01.523 AM
>   ReportCrash[19417]: Attempt to read info_array in pid 19425 failed,
>   address was 8fe53ef0 6/21/16 10:28:01.523 AM ReportCrash[19417]:
>   Attempt to read info_array in pid 19425 failed, address was 8fe53ef0
>   6/21/16 10:28:01.523 AM ReportCrash[19417]: Attempt to read info_array
>   in pid 19425 failed, address was 8fe53ef0 6/21/16 10:28:01.524 AM
>   ReportCrash[19417]: Attempt to read info_array in pid 19425 failed,
>   address was 8fe53ef0 6/21/16 10:28:01.524 AM ReportCrash[19417]:
>   Attempt to read info_array in pid 19425 failed, address was 8fe53ef0
>   6/21/16 10:28:01.539 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]:
>   (com.mcafee.reporter[19425]) Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT
>   trap: 5 6/21/16 10:28:01.539 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]:
>   (com.mcafee.reporter) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn
>   out by 10 seconds. 6/21/16 10:28:01.540 AM ReportCrash[19417]: Saved
>   crash report for McAfee Reporter[19425] version ??? to
>   /Users/acobster/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/McAfee
>   Reporter_2016-06-21-102801_Tomato.crash

These seem to suggest that a running McAfee-related process is crashing over and over. The "pushing respawn out" part seems to suggest that  it's trying to restart itself and failing. However, `grep`ing running processes for "mcafee" or "reporter" doesn't turn up anything:

```
$ ps aux | grep mcafee | grep -v grep
$ ps aux | grep reporter | grep -v grep
$
```

Furthermore, searching for "mcafee" in the Activity Monitor doesn't show me any running processes either. What's going on here? How can I stop these useless respawns?

Comment: Based on the messages, it seems like it's trying to "start up." What method did you use to uninstall McAfee? I would go into the terminal or Finder and search the folders, `/Library/Application Support`, `/Library/Preferences`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/Library/PreferencePanes`, `/Library/StartupItems` and see if you can find anything McAfee related.

Comment: Funny story: I uninstalled McAfee by deleting the .app file itself (the dedicated uninstaller app didn't work). I did this on my old laptop and booted up my current computer from a Time Machine backup of that, so McAfee was never actually installed on this machine! As you predict, I did find stuff in `/Library/Application Support`, whose removal stopped the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course right after I post this is when I think to actually look in one of the Crash Reports...

```
$ less /Users/acobster/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/McAfee Reporter_2016-06-21-102801_Tomato.crash
```

It contained a few paths where McAfee stuff appears to be lurking. When I purged those directories, the errors stopped:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/McAfee
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/McAfee/
```